# How can I check any of radio button is not selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check whether any of radio button is not checked.How can I do it?

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

     $('#delete_btn').click(function(){ as answer
         if ( !($("RadioGroup1").is(':checked')) )// THis line is not wirking..I need the code for this line
{ 


             }else{
//message
        }
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/ - that's not a question but a google request.

Comment: I searched man..I found above code..Its not working..

Comment: Can you specify exactly **what** is not working?  Are there any errors?

Answer (score 1):

you probably used a wrong selector

```
$("RadioGroup1")
```

instead of `$(".RadioGroup1")` or `$("#RadioGroup1")`

Comment: yep... this could be *part* of the problem...

Answer (score 0):

as of jQuery 1.7+ you can use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```
$(document).on('click','#delete_btn', function(){
  if($(this).prop('checked')){
    // do whatever if checked
   }
})
```

Comment: I don't think the `checked` property is meant to be on the delete button.  The button is simply what initiates the test... The `checked` property is on a radio input element...

Answer (score 0):

On the client side?

If so, query for all radio buttons, loop through them and check their "checked" status.

```
$("input:radio").each(function(){
   if($(this).attr("checked")!='checked' || !($(this).attr("checked"))){

   }
});
```

Comment: Not for all radio button..Its for a one radio button

Comment: Then maybe you should change your original question - "...check whether **any** of radio button..."

Answer (score 0):

If you selector returns results - it will return them in an array.

Similarly, if your selector returns zero elements, the array it will return will be empty.  you can simply test the length of the array that is returned -

```
$("#radioElement:checked").length
```

If the length is bigger than zero - there **are** some `:checked` radio elements under that selector.